# Is the single quote interpreted as repeating the character that follows the single quote?

Tags: microsoft-windows, terminal-emacs

When I copy some text with single quote and paste (by right clicking and choosing paste) into a emacs buffer with fundamental mode, the single quote seems interpreted as repeating the character that follows the single quote.

For example:

```
what's
```

is interpreted as

```
whatsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
```

Why does this happen?  Should I paste into a buffer with a different mode?

I am running emacs in cmd terminal of Windows 10 by `emacs -nw`.

If I run emacs in GUI by `emacs -Q`, then the problem doesn't happen.

Comment: This is not normal. Single quotes copy and paste just like any other character. I suspect this is an issue at the operating system of window manager level, but without a lot more detail I'd only be guessing.

Comment: Why not let Emacs create it's own window, instead of running it in the terrible Windows command prompt?

Comment: Pasting into a terminal will "type" pasted text as is. This might be related to some problems with character encoding. You should use the gui version instead, because that way you'll avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Works for me, Windows 10 cmd terminal, Emacs 24.5 and 25.1.

Comment: Does this happen when you start Emacs without your init file (`emacs -Q`)?

Comment: @Dan: see my update

Comment: Since it doesn't happen without your init file, you should recursively bisect your init file until you isolate the problem.

Comment: What Dan said: find the problem in your init file.